# copy into command not working in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

copy into command executes successfully but no rows are loaded. What am I doing wrong here?

COPY INTO BIKE_SHARE
FROM @~/C:\temp\snowflakedata\202109-divvy-tripdata.csv
file_format = (type = csv, skip_header=1) validation_mode='RETURN_1_rows';

Answer (score 1):

The command has been executed successfully because in Snowflake "@~" is a [user stage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-create-stage.html#user-stages) location that exists by default. Your command tries to load the file from the default user stage and if the file is not there it is executed but no rows are loaded.

Probably you are missing the step to upload your file on a stage. You should do this first using, e.g. [SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html) client to execute the PUT [command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html):

```
put file://C:\temp\snowflakedata\202109-divvy-tripdata.csv@~ auto_compress=true;
```

Then if you table definition and the file are OK you should execute your copy command and get the rows loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The copy command is being run using `VALIDATION_MODE`. This copy option allows the copy command to validate the files and not load them. So using this option, one can see the errors in the file but the data is not loaded into the target table.

> ```
> VALIDATION_MODE = RETURN_n_ROWS | RETURN_ERRORS | RETURN_ALL_ERRORS
>
> String (constant) that instructs the COPY command to validate the data files instead of loading them into the specified table; i.e. the
> ```
>
> COPY command tests the files for errors but does not load them. The
> command validates the data to be loaded and returns results based on
> the validation option specified

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html